# use same function in every call of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Ive object in js

```
var myobj = {}
```

I need that every time that you called to method in method like  `myObj.a()`
or `myObj.b()` etc it will call to the **same function** and will not call to anything else at all...

```
like myFn = function(){
return 1 + 1 ;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: A [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) would be perfect for this.

Comment: @ste2425 - Can you give example please

Comment: @shopiaT ill just be a sec,

Comment: @ste2425, is IE still not support Proxy?

Comment: @Maximus - I dont want it to support IE :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so Proxy is one option.

It is ES6 and i do not believe it can be pollyfilled so no IE support I'm affraid. As you said thats not an issue then all good.

```
var obj = {};

var objProxied = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: (target, key, reciever) => {
    console.log(`Handler hit, looking for prop ${key}`);
    return (...args) => foo(...args); // return what ever you like here
  }
});
```

Essentially how it works is you provide the proxy with the object to be 'proxied' and a map of handlers. The MDN lists all the different handlers, if you do not provide a handler then it will call down unto the object.

Your handler is provided different things depending on the type of handler. In our case the `get` receives the object its being called upon, the original `obj` and the property name.

It is important to note your handler must return a value, (where the comment is in the example) if you do not it will call down to the underlying object. This would cause an exception in our example as we would try to execute an undefined method.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

In action:

```js
var obj = {};

function foo(...args) {
  console.log('foo called With:', ...args);
}

var objProxied = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: (target, key, reciever) => {
   console.log(`Handler hit, looking for prop ${key}`);
    return (...args) => foo(...args)
  }
});

objProxied.a(10);
objProxied.b(20, 50);
```

Comment: kudos for coming up with a great ES6 solution!

Comment: Why not a stack snippet instead of jsfiddle?

Comment: @FelixKling Because i much prefer `JSFiddle` for prototyping, had it open in my browser already and to be honest not entirely sure how to add one in SO.

Comment: Done :) It's pretty straightforward: Click the "Insert snippet button", past code, click "Save & insert into post" and be done! I agree that jsfiddle is more convenient while writing the code.