# create generic handler for any function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I want to create a generic handler for any function on my object:

```
let obj = {};
let handler = function(param) {
    return 'hello ' + param;
}
```

I do not have any function defined on obj (it is = {}).
I want somehow that any call to a property on obj will invoke my handler:

```
obj.x(1);  // return 'hello 1'
obj.y(2);  // return 'hello 2'
```

Comment: would something like this work?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/40344085/1398867 I guess